# taking date as dd/mm/yy in c language

Tags: c, date

```
    # include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int d1, d2, m1, m2, year;
    printf("Enter date (dd/mm/yy): ");
    scanf("%d,%d/%d,&,d/%d", &d1,&d2,&m1,&m2,&year);
```

**Hello guys I am new in c programming so I'm trying to take the date as dd/mm/yy format but when I write it like this it gives me an output as 191/033/0 for 19/07/14 input how can i fix this? **

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int d, m, year;
    printf("Enter date (dd/mm/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &d,&m,&year);
    if (d%10==1 && d!=11) printf("%d st",d);
    else if (d%10==2 && d!=12) printf("%d nd",d);
    else if (d%10==3 && d!=13) printf("%d rd",d);
    else printf("%d th",d);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, `dd/mm/yy` **does not** mean 'two days, two months and two years'. This means 'two digits for day, month and year'. That's why you don't need so many variables.

Comment: Do you think the return value of `scanf()` is useless?

Comment: @iharob The whole scanf function is pretty useless, as far as production code goes...

Comment: @iharob, this is a minimal working example, just to show the basic concept.

Comment: @Lundin ok, agree. But still, it's a very common mistake for new programmers to ignore the return value of every function, even `malloc()`.

Comment: thanks for answer but the question is actually says that for input 19/07/14, give this output "Dated this 19th day of July, 2014.", so I should get two integer for the input and by looking the last digit I should give an output as st,nd,rd etc. but in your answer I can't deal with this :/ @ForceBru

Answer (score 1):

You need the `strftime()` function, and handle the input correctly so nothing unexpected happens

This is an example of how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char      buffer[100];
    struct tm date;

    memset(&date, 0, sizeof(date));

    printf("Enter date (dd/mm/yy): ");
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d/%d/%d", &date.tm_mday, &date.tm_mon, &date.tm_year) == 3)
    {
        const char *format;

        format = "Dated %A %dth of %B, %Y";
        if (strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, &date) > sizeof(buffer))
            fprintf(stderr, "there was a problem converting the string\n");
        else
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```